# Sum values for a month from weekly data weighted by day

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a sheet with weekly values, and I'd like to calculate what the monthly value is. The catch is that if a week's value say 70 is split across two months (say 3 days in January and 4 days in February) - I'd like the calculated (summed) value for January to take the value for the week and (3/7) x 70 = 30 for January and (4/7) x 70 = 40 summed for February.

Example sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19LClrTXihPfwRtvX7nrOfKpz7aLC-RrczpED-U8ufmo/edit#gid=0

Any help on a formula to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sorry opened it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY({TEXT(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), "m♦mmmm yyyy"), 
 TRANSPOSE(D2:2)-IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(D1:1))), 4)=0, 
 DAYS(EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), 0), TRANSPOSE(D1:1))/7*TRANSPOSE(D2:2), )+
 QUERY({""; IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(D1:1))),4)=0, 
 DAYS(EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), 0), TRANSPOSE(D1:1))/7*TRANSPOSE(D2:2), )}, 
 "limit "&COLUMNS(D1:1), 0)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where not Col2 = 0 group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0)), 
 "(.+)♦", ))
```

[image: 0]

---

## FIX:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY({TEXT(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), "m♦mmmm yyyy"), 
 TRANSPOSE(D2:2)-IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(D1:1))), 4)=0, 
 DAYS(EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), 0), TRANSPOSE(D1:1))/7*TRANSPOSE(D2:2), )+
 QUERY({""; IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(D1:1))),4)=0, 
 DAYS(EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), 0), TRANSPOSE(D1:1))/7*TRANSPOSE(D2:2), )}, 
 "limit "&COLUMNS(D1:1), 0)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where not Col2 = 0 group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0)), 
 "(.+)♦", ), 
 IF(LEN(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY({TEXT(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), "m♦mmmm yyyy"), 
 TRANSPOSE(D2:2)-IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(D1:1))), 4)=0, 
 DAYS(EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), 0), TRANSPOSE(D1:1))/7*TRANSPOSE(D2:2), )+
 QUERY({""; IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(D1:1))),4)=0, 
 DAYS(EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), 0), TRANSPOSE(D1:1))/7*TRANSPOSE(D2:2), )}, 
 "limit "&COLUMNS(D1:1), 0)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where not Col2 = 0 group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0)), 
 "(.+)♦", ),"select Col1",0)), MONTH(LEFT(
 QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY({TEXT(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), "m♦mmmm yyyy"), 
 TRANSPOSE(D2:2)-IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(D1:1))), 4)=0, 
 DAYS(EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), 0), TRANSPOSE(D1:1))/7*TRANSPOSE(D2:2), )+
 QUERY({""; IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(D1:1))),4)=0, 
 DAYS(EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), 0), TRANSPOSE(D1:1))/7*TRANSPOSE(D2:2), )}, 
 "limit "&COLUMNS(D1:1), 0)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where not Col2 = 0 group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0)), 
 "(.+)♦", ),"select Col1", 0), 3)&1)&RIGHT(
 QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY({TEXT(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), "m♦mmmm yyyy"), 
 TRANSPOSE(D2:2)-IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(D1:1))), 4)=0, 
 DAYS(EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), 0), TRANSPOSE(D1:1))/7*TRANSPOSE(D2:2), )+
 QUERY({""; IF(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(D1:1))),4)=0, 
 DAYS(EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(D1:1), 0), TRANSPOSE(D1:1))/7*TRANSPOSE(D2:2), )}, 
 "limit "&COLUMNS(D1:1), 0)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where not Col2 = 0 group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0)), 
 "(.+)♦", ),"select Col1", 0), 4), )*1}, 
 "select Col1,Col2 order by Col3")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. This formula gives me the values for each month, but I'd like to split the value for Week Beginning 1/28/2019 of 75 across January and February

1/28 1/29 1/30 1/31
2/1 2/3 2/4 is the week M-F
so for January I'd like to count 4 days worth: (4/7) * 75 = 42.85
February 3 days worth: (3/7) * 75 = 32.14
and add those values to January and February respectively.

Comment: not sure I understand. can you provide example of desired output in your sheet?

Comment: Added an example manual row. 
I want to calculate a value for each day, since some weeks (Monday through Sunday) cut across months, I need a formula to weight it by days in each month for the weeks that cut across

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! Does this have to be transposed in terms of output?

Comment: nope, you can insert a TRANSPOSE between ARRAYFORMULA and REGEXREPLACE

Comment: Hi again. For some reason when there is a value entered in for October 2019, the formula breaks down and the results start with October 2019. I've tried to decipher what's going on but to no avail. Could you help here?

Comment: this is caused coz oct is 10 so it orders itself like 10,1,2,3, etc

Comment: Thank you player0!